# Python keeps saying NameError: name 'name' is not defined

Tags: python

```
def main():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    age = raw_input("How old are you?")
    color = raw_input("What is your favorite color?")

print "Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, " \
"and your favorite color is %s." % (name, age, color)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am trying to replicate the following code from Codeacademy:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
quest = raw_input("What is your quest?")
color = raw_input("What is your favorite color?")

print "Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, " \
"and your favorite color is %s." % (name, quest, color)
```

Answer (score 3):

Print should be in the scope of the main function in order to acces its variables:

```
def main():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    age = raw_input("How old are you?")
    color = raw_input("What is your favorite color?")

    print "Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, " \
    "and your favorite color is %s." % (name, age, color)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This should do.

Answer (score 1):

`name`, `age`, and `color` are all local to `main`.  Thus, you cannot access them outside of the function.

I think the best solution here would be to indent that `print` line one level:

```
def main():
    name = raw_input("What is your name?")
    age = raw_input("How old are you?")
    color = raw_input("What is your favorite color?")

    print "Ah, so your name is %s, your quest is %s, " \
        "and your favorite color is %s." % (name, age, color)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, it is in the same scope as `name`, `age`, and `color` and can access them just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only time you set `name` is when you call the `main` function. The only time you call the `main` function is *after* you call the `print` function (because the print statement isn't part of `main`). Therefore, name is undefined.

If you intended to replicate the codeacademy code, you need to adjust the indentation of the print statement so that it is at the same level as the `raw_input` statements. This is because python uses the amount of indentation to know which block a line of code belongs to.  You want the print statement to be in the same block as the input statements.

For example:

```
def main():
    name = ...
    age = ...
    color = ...

    print ...
```